# Pygame, are there any ways to view the entire event queue from a display?

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, pygame

As the question stated, I was wondering if there is any actual way to view the whole event queue at the end of runtime. I'm very new to pygame and the only 2 methods I'm familiar relating to events so far are: pygame.event.get() and pygame.event.poll(). Thing is, both of these method removes it's corresponding event in the queue - most likely to save space I assume.

So that means I need to be able to print out the whole event at the very end of runtime, my code are as follows:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,300))
thing = 0
while thing < 100000000:
    thing += 1

event = pygame.event.get()
print (event)
pygame.quit()
```

The problem with this code is that whenever I try to move the pygame window, it became unresponsive and I wasn't able to interact with it, this happens every time I try to create a new pygame window, I'm able to click and move it around - but the moment I click the close button, the window unresponsive and I had to shut it down via the console. Is there a more effective alternative to do this?

Comment: Problem is long-running `while` loop which doesn't get events from system and it may stops your window. Use `pygame.event.get()` inside loop. And window closing button doesn't close window automatically - you have to do on your own. You have to get event, check if it QUIT event and quit `while` loop

Comment: It returned me with nothing, what I wanted to do is view the entire queue. I also would also question if the "get event" thing is true since the above code did print out some event, but in just in a unresponsive style

Comment: it returns only one event from `queue` - you have to use `for` loop to get all events. But at start queue can be empty - Pygame had no time to get new events from system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run long-running `while` loop which stops window - it doesn't close immediatelly - but your don't get events from system to recognize `QUIT` event and exit loop.

When you click closing button then it doesn't close window. It sends event `QUIT` to your program and you can decide what to do - you can exit loop and then it ends program, but you can also save some data before close, or you can ask user if it really want to exit, etc.

It is simple standard `mainloop` which gets events, and it ends program when you press closing button (event `QUIT`).

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,300))

# --- mainloop / event loop ---
running = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print (event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # <-- closing button was pressed
            running = False # it will exit `while` loop

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I added more exmplanation.

Comment: Thank you :D, this was what I was looking for - does pygame only gathers event when a loop has been executed? I thought it does it automatically gathers event once a display has been created.

Comment: Also, what do these number represent? I did "print(pygame.QUIT)" and it returned me the integer 12. Are there names/documentations or a table somewhere that I can look at that represents each event? I'd like some link/pointers to do my individual research

Comment: It gets new events from system when you execute `event.get()` or [event.pump()](http://pygame.event.pump()) and it keeps in queue - without `get()` or `pump()` even `mouse.get_pos()` will not work.

Comment: events are numbered but instead using numbers like `if event.type == 12` it is easier to use names. See official documentation for PyGame: [event](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) to see other events (like KEYDOWN, KEYUP, MOUSEMOTION, etc.)

Comment: I means it uses unique number for every event to recognize them but there are constants like `pygame.QUIT = 12` and you don't have to remember numbers - you can use `pygame.QUIT` which is easier to remeber. It is popular method not only in Python but also in C/C++ \